# Representation of real or complex numbers as vector of coefficients of polynomials.

Tags: polynomials, computer-science

Assuming we have a polynomial $$p(x) = \sum_{k=0}^N c_k x^k, \hspace{1cm} c_k \in \mathbb{N}$$

As far as I know we can create find polynomials having roots being any **algebraic** real number. Are there any standards of how to store such information?

For example:

$$p(x) = x^2-2=0 \Leftrightarrow \cases{x_1=-\sqrt{2}\\x_2 = \sqrt{2}}$$

If we store $$[c_2,c_1,c_0] = [1,0,-2]$$ in a vector that requires three integers and can store that we mean the real number $\sqrt{2}$. Something that no resolution of a fraction or floating point standard  could. But how to store which of the roots we intend?

Comment: Real numbers can be sorted. Keep the desired rank along with the coefficients. For complex numbers, you can use lexicographical ordering, f.i. by real part then imaginary part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Thom codes: you can distinguish a root $x_0$ of $p$ between the other roots of $p$ by the signs of the numbers $p'(x_0),p''(x_0),\dots,p^{(N)}(x_0)$.

Relevant link: [Manipulation of real roots of polynomials: Isolating Intervals or Thom's Codes](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/2685023_Manipulation_of_real_roots_of_polynomials_Isolating_Intervals_or_Thom%27s_Codes).

Comment: Yes, great! This is brilliant, I think.